# Why would a TCP connection have headers on every packet?

Tags: python, network-programming

When working with AWS using Python and the boto3 library, if you run a command on a remote docker container, it gives you a websocket (TCP) to connect to in order to get the output of the command.

Python code for reading data from the stream can look like this:

```py
import construct as c
...

Message = c.Struct(
    "HeaderLength" / c.Int32ub,
    "MessageType" / c.PaddedString(32, "ascii"),
    "SchemaVersion" / c.Int32ub,
    "CreateDate" / c.Int64ub,
    "SequenceNumber" / c.Int64sb,
    "Flags" / c.Int64ub,
    "MessageID" / c.Array(16, c.Byte),
    "PayloadDigest" /  c.Array(32, c.Byte),
    "PayloadType" / c.Int32ub,
    "PayloadLength" / c.Int32ub,
    "Payload" / c.Array(c.this.PayloadLength, c.Byte),
)

connection = ...

while True:
    response = connection.recv()

    message = Message.parse(response)

    print("Payload Message:", payload_message.Payload)
```

TCP already contains things like sequence numbers, and will already re-assemble the data in proper order, and ensure no data is missing. Why would AWS add another header on top of that to essentially do the same thing?

Comment: TCP doesn't have message boundaries, it's just a flat stream of data. You need an application protocol on top of that.

Comment: Look at the fields in that header, most of them have nothing to do with sequencing. TCP doesn't have a Message Type.

Comment: I would expect a single header that says things like the message type, the message length, the checksum, and then a single, massive payload that's split up between multiple recv() calls - not one header per message. Why have one header per `recv` call?

Comment: There is no header per recv call. The headers are per WebSocket message. See your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070745/is-code-that-relies-on-packet-boundaries-for-a-tcp-stream-inherently-unreliable about the relationship between recv and messages.

Comment: Whether or not recv calls are related to messages, in this code example, there's one header per recv call. Why does each WebSocket message need a header, where the payloads are all related?

Comment: Because they don't have to be all the same. You can put different types in each message. WebSockets is a general-purpose wrapper protocol, so it's designed for flexibility.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more flexible to let you decide, if, and what type of headers you need? In this case, allowing you to have a single header instead of thousands of headers for a large payload?

Comment: That would make the protocol more complicated, by making the header variable like that.

Comment: You don't need thousands of headers for a large payload. You send one header with a long payload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248812/discussion-between-john-and-barmar).